# AngularJS Material mdDialog and unhandled rejection on a promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have no idea why but I'm getting `unhandled rejection` error for AngularJS Material `mdDialog` on hide/cancel

Code for the `mdDialog`:

```
$scope.addAttendee = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController,
    templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
    locals: {parent: $scope}
})
.then(function(response){
    if(angular.isDefined(response)){
        attendees.push(response);
    }

    console.log(attendees);
    console.log(attendees.length);
})
```

when I will remove a promise then the dialog box can be closed w/o error message.

Any clue what is going on with that?

Comment: 'unhandled rejection' means that a promise was rejected but the error wasn't handled. Add `.catch` to find out what the error is, and do this every time when there's a chance that a promise can be rejected.

Comment: try add the reject function like this :    `.then(function(response){}, function(reject){ //console.log(reject)})` to se the error.

Comment: i see mdDialog still give you some headache lol. greetings. dude @JackTheKnife

Comment: It is normal for [$mdDialog.cancel()](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-cancel-response) to return a rejected promise

Comment: If [$mgDialog.hide()](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-hide-response) is getting an unhandled rejection, it is likely the code in the `.then` block is throwing an error. Possibly the variable `attendees` is not an array thus `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push'`. Add a `.catch` block after the `.then` block to see the error.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco `function(reject)` is not working - throws `undefined` error.

Comment: @georgeawg it says that `response` is `undefined` for `.catch` block

Comment: @georgeawg I know how to debug, but `.catch` didn't brought nothing new (what the error is) to my issue. At first if `response` is `undefined` then it shouldn't pass `angular.isDefined(response)` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came that I need a function when there are no changes (hide/cancel) for a promise from `mdDiaglog`.

Code after update

```
$scope.addAttendee = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController,
    templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
    locals: {parent: $scope}
})
.then(
    function(response){
        if(angular.isDefined(response)){
            attendees.push(response);

            console.log(attendees);
            console.log(attendees.length);
        }
    },
    function(){
        //no changes
    }
)
.catch(
    function(error) {
        console.error('Error: ' + error);
    }
);
```

Comment: or anyone: how would you load/display an mdDialog box to show the error in the catch call?